# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate open (+) and close (x) buttons for main navigation. It's not working properly and I am getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle( "active" );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="nav-toggle"   href="#navi" data-toggle="collapse" 
 data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" ) would be null, meaning it's not finding any elements. Is it running after the document has loaded?

Comment: Could you provide some code as to how this is all loaded? Nothing wrong with your listener, it's just not finding the element.

Comment: Have you read Felix Kling's question "[Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById()` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)"

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. It could be an issue of when the javascript runs or a conflict with your data library.  The library for collapse might be overwriting your id.  Try to use a page inspector like firebug to find out if the id changes after load.

Below is your code toggling the link to red.

```js
document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle( "active" );
});
```

```css
.active {color:red}
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle"   href="#navi" data-toggle="collapse" 
 data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span>test</span>
</a>
```